# I can't seem to start a second animation after stopping the first one on javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

Currently I'm trying to start a second animation after stopping the first one. The first animation did manage to stop but the second animation won't manage to start. I don't know what is going wrong with my codes and I don't know how to test to see which part is going wrong.

```js
function flyRocket() {
    let animatedElement = document.querySelector('.rocket');
    animatedElement.style.animation = 'none';
    moveRocket();
}

function moveRocket() {
    let movingElement = document.querySelector('.rocket');
    movingElement.classList.add('move-up-animation');
}
```

```css
#Rocket {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}

.rocket {
  position: relative;
  animation: animate 0.5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(-4px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(4px);
  }
}

.rocket::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00d0ff, transparent);
}

.rocket::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);    
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00d0ff, transparent);
    filter: blur(20px);
}

.move-up-animation {
    animation: moveUpAnimation 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes moveUpAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='scene'>
    <div class='rocket'>
        <img id='Rocket' src='rocket.png'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is `flyRocket` called? also note that inline style has higher specificity than class based style - so `animatedElement.style.animation = 'none'` will prevent any animation based on class

Comment: I forgot to include it there's a button that has that onclick function.

Comment: still, my comment explains why

Comment: Then can I ask what's the best way to fix it?

Comment: split the animation from `.rocket` selector to another class - call it whatever, and add that class to the element. On the click, remove that class and add the class you are adding now

Comment: Never mind, thanks for the hint i fixed it by removing the inline style property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split the animation from `.rocket` selector to another class - call it whatever, and add that class to the element. On the click, remove that class and add the class you are adding now

Like this

```js
function flyRocket() {
    let animatedElement = document.querySelector('.rocket');
    animatedElement.classList.remove('up-down-animation');
    moveRocket();
}

function moveRocket() {
    let movingElement = document.querySelector('.rocket');
    movingElement.classList.add('move-up-animation');
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', flyRocket);
```

```css
#Rocket {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
}

.rocket {
  position: relative;
}
.up-down-animation {
  animation: animate 0.5s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(-4px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(4px);
  }
}

.rocket::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00d0ff, transparent);
}

.rocket::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);    
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background: linear-gradient(#00d0ff, transparent);
    filter: blur(20px);
}

.move-up-animation {
    animation: moveUpAnimation 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes moveUpAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='scene'>
    <div class='rocket up-down-animation'>
        <img id='Rocket' src='rocket.png'>
    </div>
</div>
```